# Rewarded video website for browser games/websites

Tags: web-development, game-development, advertising

I'm working on an online browser based game and looking at introducing rewarded videos for the users to get extra boost in the game.

I could find plenty of rewarded video websites/services (adMob from Google and so on ...) for mobile apps or html5/flash games but nothing for a traditional game/website developed in html/php and codeigniter.

Any idea who offers this kind of tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some research on advertising agencies.

**PropellerAds.com** offer:

1. On-click
2. Banner
3. In-banner video

**BrightRoll** offer:

1. Mainly video ads

However, you need your own video player to serve ads (could this work within your game?)

**VidRoll.com** offer:

1. Videos ads

**VeoClick.com** offer:

1. Video ads (pre-roll video)
2. In-baner ads

These companies offer videos ads which could be incorporated into a website/game.

Comment: veoclick seems dead, or maybe you have another link to provide?

Comment: You're right, I have an alternative HaxHax.com offer similar services.